# Laplace equation with source term of $\delta(y) ( H(x) - H(-x) )$

Tags: complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, dirac-delta

Is it possible to solve the following equation for F(x,y) analytically? I was trying to solve it using conformal mapping (e.g. sin(z) transformation) however, I couldn't find an answer.

$$
\frac{d^2 F}{dx^2} + \frac{d^2 F}{dy^2} = \delta(y) ( H(x) - H(-x) ) 
$$

where $\delta(y)$ is the **delta function** and $H(x)$ is the **Heaviside step function**.

If it is helpful, we can assume that the PDE domain is finite: $|x| < x_0$ and $|y| < y_0$.

Comment: By "step function" do you mean Heaviside function?

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question.